# Separate an image into regions

Tags: iphone, imageview, regions

I have a view with an imageview and a tableview below it. The imageview contains an image of a human body.  Now what I'd like to do is to separate the image into three portions: The head, the thorax and the abdominal cavity. The tableview also has three rows, each corresponding to the sections of the body mentioned above.When I select or click any of these regions I want to scroll through the corresponding rows of the table and navigate to another viewcontroller which will serve as a detail view controller. So let's say I choose head, I want to navigate to another page that explains head in detail. I get the same effect when I select any of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` instance attached to the image view. First off, you will have to set the `UIImageView`'s `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`. After attaching the gesture recognizer, you should resolve the touch to its region in the gesture handler.

```
- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    CGPoint locationInView = [tapGesture locationInView:tapGesture.view];

    /* Resolve the location here */
}
```

Now resolution is based on how you will define the regions. If they are just rectangles, declare three `CGRect` objects as instance variables and set them appropriately and do something like this,

```
if ( CGRectContainsPoint(headRect, locationInView) ) {
    /* It's a head, load its view controller */
} else if ( ... ) {
    ....
```

Or if the regions are a bit more complicated, use `UIBezierPath` or `CGPathRef`.